# Classical Mechanics as an approximation of Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electrons

I want to show an equality:

We know from Ehrenfest's theorem that 
$$ \frac{d \langle x   \rangle(t)}{dt}=  \left\langle \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} \right\rangle
$$
I'd like to derive the following statement:
$$\frac{ d\langle x  \rangle(t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial  \langle H  \rangle}{\partial\langle p  \rangle}
$$

Because this would be in my Opinion the "total" classical limit: We observe a quantity energy and a quantity momentum, and that the derivation of energy with respect to momentum gives as the change of position with respect to time.

Is it possible to derive the statement that I want to derive? If not exactly, what are the approximations that have to be made? I could show it under the condition that the hamilton operator and the momentum operator share eigenstates, but I'd like to know how mutch it is possible in general.

Edit: 
By 
$$ 
 \frac{\partial  \langle H  \rangle}{\partial\langle p  \rangle}
$$ 
I mean that I look at the change of $\langle H \rangle$, when I change the state $\Psi$ in a way that changes the mean value of momentum. I could do that by constructing a function $f(p)$ that maps the number $p$ to a state $\Psi_p$ in a way that $\langle \Psi_p | \hat{p} | \Psi_p \rangle = p$ suffices. One example could be a gaussian wave package with a mean momentum p. Then I can take the derivative 
$
\frac{d}{dp} \langle \Psi_p | \hat{H} | \Psi_p \rangle
$.

There is definitely not a unique way to define such a function $\Psi_p$, but if one can show the the equality I am looking for for one such function $\Psi_p$, without making use of the exact form that $\Psi_p$ takes, wouldn't the quantity $
\frac{\partial  \langle H  \rangle}{\partial\langle p  \rangle}
 = \frac{d}{dp} \langle \Psi_p | \hat{H} | \Psi_p \rangle
$ still be well defined?

Second edit: The origin of my question is the semiclassical model of electron dynamics, as it is explained in Chapter 12 of solid state physics by Ashcroft. Here the electron energy $\epsilon_k$ with $\hat{H} \Psi_k = \epsilon _k \Psi_k$ is effectively interpreted as hamiltonian, and wavepackets of electrons with mean crystal momentum $k$ are interpreted as classical particles.

Comment: Your statement is non-sensical - $\langle H \rangle$ is not a function of $\langle p \rangle$ in general, so how are you taking that derivative?

Comment: I can define a function that maps $p$ to a state $\Psi_{p}$, whose mean value then is p (I construct the function in a way that $\langle H \rangle  = p $ holds. There are many functions that can do that. Then I can derive < H >, which is a function of p, with respect to p.

Comment: Please do define this operation explicitly, because currently I don't understand at all how you want to do it or why this should be a physically meaningful operation.

Comment: I don't understand why it is unclear what I'm asking for. It wrote down an equality and I want to know if this equality holds, or what approximations have to made that it holds. I edited the post to explain every term that might be unclear.

Comment: If there are multiple ways to deform $|\Psi⟩$ into $|\Psi_p⟩$ that do the same increase in $⟨\Psi_p|\hat p|\Psi_p⟩$ but different increases in $⟨\Psi_p|\hat H|\Psi_p⟩$ (which is pretty much correct), then that would mean that $\partial ⟨H⟩/\partial ⟨p⟩$ cannot actually be defined, no?

Comment: Then stronger constraints about $|\Psi_p \rangle$ would solve this problem ... for example by saying that $\Psi_p$ is supposed to be a gaussian wave package with a given uncertainty in momentum and position.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you can't expect to recover general classical mechanics by simply making averages in quantum mechanics. Apart from very special cases, you can recover it *only in the limit $\hslash\to 0$*.

In such limit, something similar of what you expect can be proved. In particular, it holds when considering (squeezed) coherent states $C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)$ centred on $(q,\xi)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ (with a suitable $\hslash$-dependence). First of all we suppose that $C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)$ is in the form domain of the Hamiltonian. Then
$$\lim_{\hslash\to 0}\langle H_{\hslash}\rangle_{C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)}=: h(q,\xi)$$
defines a function of the phase space. Such function has many nice properties of the classical energy, e.g.
$$h(t,q,\xi):=\lim_{\hslash\to 0}\langle H_{\hslash}\rangle_{e^{-i\frac{t}{\hslash}H_{\hslash}}C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)}= h(q,\xi)\; ;$$
i.e. it is an integral of motion.

On the other hand:
$$\lim_{\hslash\to 0}\langle x_{\hslash}\rangle_{e^{-i\frac{t}{\hslash}H_{\hslash}}C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)}=: q(t)\; ,\\
\lim_{\hslash\to 0}\langle p_{\hslash}\rangle_{e^{-i\frac{t}{\hslash}H_{\hslash}}C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)}=: \xi(t)\; ;$$
with $q(0)=q$ and $\xi(0)=\xi$.

Finally, it is possible to prove that $q(t)$ and $\xi(t)$ obey the expected equations of motion:
$$\left\{\begin{align}\dot{q}(t)&=\partial_{\xi}h(q(t),\xi(t))\\\dot{p}(t)&=-\partial_{q}h(q(t),\xi(t))\end{align}\right .\; .$$

Comment: I just wanted to underline that an average means many-many measurements (divided by the number of measurements), i.e., the CM is an *inclusive* picture. When you look at a moving classical body, you actually measure its positions with help of photons and add the separate (or one-photon) points together. Doing so, we associate  a finite-sized body with only one point. When the body becomes small, the spread of different observed points becomes essential (Heisenberg uncertainty).

Comment: Where can I find out more about what you describe? Has this some name? What do you mean by $C_h$ centered on $(q, \xi)$?

Comment: What I describe is usually called classical limit ;-) In the simple formulation with coherent states, it can be found in [this paper by Klaus Hepp](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103859623). A more thorough (and maybe complicated) description using semiclassical analysis is given by [Pierre-Louis Lions and Thierry Paul](https://eudml.org/doc/39445). The squeezed coherent state is $C_{\hslash}(q,\xi)=e^{\frac{i}{\sqrt{\hslash}}(\xi x - q p)}\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the lowest energy eigenvector of the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: With this setting, you have to take $x_{\hslash}=\sqrt{\hslash}x$ and $p_{\hslash}=\sqrt{\hslash}p$ (where $x$ and $p$ are the position and momentum operators, in their $\hslash$-independent version)

Comment: although this is just written for certain cases (and I still have to work through that), basically that's what I want to know about. Thank you :)

Comment: @Quantumwhisp No problem ;-) What I wrote for coherent states actually works for essentially every quantum state, with a caveat: the limit state is in general a probability distribution on the phase space, and not just a point. Such distribution is pushed forward by the classical flow; and evolved quantum states converge to the corresponding pushed forward classical measures as expected. Coherent states are just the special case that correspond to a classical probability distribution concentrated in a point of the phase space.